# How come differential entropy can be negative but mutual information can't?

Tags: entropy, information-theory, mutual-information

**Differential entropy**,

$$H(X) = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x) \ln p(x) dx,$$
ordinarily is positive (the negative sign in front actually makes the entire expression positive). However, it can be negative for certain families of distributions. In other words, some densities have negative entropy. Does this only apply to differential entropy, whereas **discrete entropy** is the one that is always positive?

If differential entropy is included in (differential) **mutual information**,

$$ I(X,Y) = H(X) - H(X|Y),$$

why isn't mutual information ever negative, given that entropy might take on negative values?

or should I be asking whether there are situations where $H(X|Y) > H(X)$? Besides this, $H(X|Y) = H(X,Y) - H(Y)$, whose right-hand side would become unrealistically larger than the left-hand side if $H(Y)<0$.

Comment: Can you give an example of a distribution where differential entropy is negative?

Comment: Uniform distribution with width < 1 can be an example

Answer (score 3):

Differential entropy is usually denoted by lowercase $h$, so I'll use that notation. Discrete entropy is always positive (because $-\log p(x)$ is always nonnegative and so all the summands in the entropy definition).

For the mutual information ($I(X;Y)=h(X)-h(X|Y)$), we always have the following inequality (Elements of Information Theory by Cover & Thomas, Second Edition, Page 256):
$$h(X|Y)\leq h(X)$$
So it is nonnegative. This is intuitive because when you're given extra information, the uncertainty will either decrease or stays the same.

Comment: Could you show more explicitly how this answers the question(s)?

Comment: I've added a reference for the inequality @RichardHardy

Comment: Thank you. I am not challenging your claims. I only meant to ask what I can conclude from what you wrote. E.g. what is the answer to the question *How come differential entropy can be negative but mutual information can't?* and other ones in the post?

Comment: Yeah, the answer actually relied on the equation in the OP

Comment: Thank you. That does seem to answer the part of the question regarding why mutual information cannot be negative.

Comment: The other main question is "Does this only apply to differential entropy, whereas discrete entropy is the one that is always positive?" and I answered it in the first paragraph saying that the discrete entropy is always nonnegative, while differential entropy can be as OP also says. Other than this, there is a sentence in the end, starting with "Besides this", but I couldn't extract a clear question out of it. Do you think something else is missing?

Comment: Let the OP have a say on that. I just tried to make the answer as clear as possible. Sometimes what is obvious for the answerer is not obvious for someone else, so I prefer very explicit answers. Thank you for your help!

Comment: just came on now and think the 2 situations ruminated in the last paragraph of the question could empirically occur if $H(X)$ or $H(Y)$ turned out to be negative. In other words, would violate those inequality rules

Comment: In fact, multivariate mutual information was developed because in 1962 it was first proved the possible negativity of mutual-information for degrees higher than 2, which if we backtrack might explain why (or stem from how) differential entropy has loose bounds as well